# Pass parameter into action

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dependency-injection

was not sure how to name the question correctly, so here is what I want to achieve. I have a generic iterator method, which goes over the properties of an object recursively

```
internal static void IterateProperties(Object element, Action<Object> action)
{
  // recursively iterate over objects properties recursively
  // ...
  action.Invoke(element);
}
```

Then I have a method which can be passed into that method.

```
private static void ResetSomeProperty(Object element)
{
  // do something with the element
}
```

Which is then called at some point.

```
IterateProperties(element, ResetSomeProperty);
```

So far so good. Now I would like to pass some other dependency into the `ResetSomeProperty` method:

```
//Pseudocode
IterateProperties(element, ResetSomeProperty(externalDictionary));

    private static void ResetSomeProperty(
      Object element, 
      [externalProperty] Dictionary<int, int> dictionary)
    {
      // do something with the element
    }
```

I hope you get what I need. I can't think of a design which allows me that (other than going to a external static class which provides that information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a lambda to close over the dictionary in question:

```
IterateProperties(element, ele => ResetSomeProperty(ele, externalDictionary));
```

Comment: The code won't compile. Can you maybe post a complete example?

Comment: @derape It will absolutely compile given the code that you showed.  If it won't compile then the code that you showed isn't correct.  You also haven't stated why it won't compile.

Comment: I was wrong, I simplified my example. Now it works! Thank you

Comment: Still I do not completely understand how the runtime is handling this. Can you maybe explain in a few words how that is executed and how the dicionary is passed within the `IterateProperties` method? =)

Comment: You can do a web search on closures to see what's going on here.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I also noticed that that I lose type safety during development when I change the Action parameters right?

Comment: @derape Everything about this is statically typed.  None of the type checking is going on at runtime here.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will need to change the `Action<object>` parameter in IterateProperties to an `Action<object,Dictionary<int,int>>`. That way, you'll have something like this:

```
internal static void IterateProperties(Object element, Dictionary<int,int> dict, Action<Object, Dictionary<int,int>> action)
{
  // recursively iterate over objects properties recursively
  // ...
  action.Invoke(element, dict);
}
```

And the method call to IterateProperties will be:

```
IterateProperties(element, externalDictionary, ResetSomeProperty);
```

Comment: I do not want to add a additional parameter, because the method to be used should be exchangable with different operations on the element to change